# javascript converter

Tags: javascript

I am having trouble finishing this javascript to convert coffee prices..I downloaded a debugger and it keeps telling me that price is undefined and i dont understand..here is the script..

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Coffee House</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      var drink, ounces, price;

      prompt ( "Enter the drink type: espresso, latte, cappuccino, americano" );
      prompt ( "Enter the oz: 8, 12, 16" )

      var shots = prompt ( "Enter the number of shots" )

      if ( drink == "espresso")
        price = 1.40;

      if (( drink == "latte") || (drink == "cappuccino" )) {
        if ( ounce == 8 )
          price = 1.95;
        else if ( ounce == 12 )
          price = 2.35;
        else if ( ounce == 16 )
          price = 2.75;
      }

      if ( drink == "americano" )
        price = 1.20 + ( ( (ounce -8)/8 ) * .30 );

      price = price + ( (shots) * .50 );
      price = "price" * 1.055;
      price = Math.round( price * 100 )/100;
      alert( "Your " + ounce + "oz. " + drink + "with " + shots + "shots of espresso costs: $ " +price );
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Try adding price in your var statement.

Comment: price is local , make it global using var drink, ounces,orice;

Comment: can you explain exactly how to do that please?

Answer (score 2):

You have several problems with your JavaScript.

1. First, update the JavaScript to declare the "price" variable.
   var drink, ounces, price;
2. Next, you need to set the variables based upon the response from the "prompt" statements.

   var ounces = prompt ( "Enter the oz: 8, 12, 16" )

   var shots = prompt ( "Enter the number of shots" )
3. You are doing a string compare of a variable "ounce" instead of "ounces". This is the undefined variable after fixing up 1 and 2 above.
4. You are doing math on the varible price although you are using it in one spot as a string instead of the variable value.  Remove the quotes from "price" when doing your arithmetic.

After applying these changes you will see something of the effect:
Your 8oz. lattewith 1shots of espresso costs: $ 2.58

Comment: I dont know how to add the price to the var statement or the var part..sorry im confused guys

Comment: Simply update the existing line to include "price" as I have shown above.

Comment: Ok I have altered it is that correct? Im still not getting a price at the end

Comment: basically every line i have written price= firebug is telling me that price is not defined..and it also tells me ounce is not defined..thanks for your help i really appreciate it

Answer (score 0):

You need to define "price" as a var before trying to assign it a value.